# Setting PHP Session variables with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a pretty simple issue which I just can't seem to resolve. I have the following ajax request which sets a PHP Session variable

```
  $.post("http://mytestdomain.com/test.php", {"data": 'success'});
```

And this code in the PHP file to generate and echo the Session variables

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test_text']= $_POST['data'];
  echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['test_text'];
```

However this keeps returning the following error message

```
  Notice: Undefined index: data in /var/www/test.php on line 2
```

If I post a demo URL into my browser like this

```
 http://mytestdomain.com/test.php?data=11111
```

Then the results are echoed correctly.

So my question is, how do I pass via jQuery Ajax data to a PHP session variable and have it saved?

Thanks

Comment: So can you do post much more complete code?

Comment: This is the complete code, it's for testing purposes

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($_POST)` and post the result

Answer (score 1):

In your `test.php` file, try the following:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['test_text']= $_REQUEST['data'];
 echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['test_text'];
```

Comment: Check test here, using your code but with a $_REQUEST method. http://checkourprogress.co.uk/test/test.html